# How to set quota per directory/sub-directory in Ubuntu

Tags: server, 20.04, xfs

At the moment I use Oracle VM on a local environment, but the final intention is to utilize it in the server.

Filesystem type is `xfs` and the OS of VM is Ubuntu but if needed I can install any other one.

**What I want to do** is, the server has some devs and each connect via SSH. The `/home` is mounted on `/dev/sda1` where `/` is. `/dev/sda2` is mounted on `/app` with below structure:

```
/app
    project1
        v1
        v1.0.1
    project2
        v0.1
        v0.2
    designs
        d1
        d2
```

There are some users like `user1`, `users2`, etc. `user1` has only access to `/app/project1/v1` and `user2` has only access to `/app/project2/v0.1`.

I have tried restricting quota with `xfs_quota`, but this application can only restrict quota on the main directory (in my case, `/app`), and it cannot set quota for `/app/project1/v1` for `user1`, and when I run this command:

```
xfs_quota -xc 'limit bsoft=5g bhard=5d user1' /app/project1/v1
```

I get this error:

> xfs_quota: cannot setup path for mount `/app/project1/v1`: No such device or address

`lsblk`'s result:

```
sda
|
--sda1
--sda2
 |--root 20G lvm /
 |--home 60G lvm /home
```

I don't want to limit specific user on whole `/home`, but I need to restrict them on specific directories. In my case, I want to limit `user1` to `project1` to `5g` for example and limit him to `designs/d1` to 4g. The directories in the future will be created and added more, and I just want to add limitation for each newly created directories.